# Dynamic Input Selector Based on Uploaded Data

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Thanks in advance for your help. I understand how to manipulate dynamic inputs based off of other inputs for pre-defined datasets.
i.e. Load a car dataset. User selects Radio button to say they only want to look at blue cars. This changes the options in some Input Selector on the UI.

However, if I want to allow a user to upload a csv file, how do I dynamically update all of the relevant widgets.
i.e. User uploads their data, an *Input Selector displays all variables in the dataset* for plots and regressions.

The italicized part is my trouble.

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("My R Shiny App"),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file', 'Choose file to upload.'),
    #Select Box: y
    selectInput("y_input", label = h5("Select Time Series/Response Variable"),
                choices = names(myData),
                selected = NULL)

  )
) 
)
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)

#Run once when app is launched
#Load data

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #Run once each time a user visits the app
  #Put code to build a distinct set of reactive objects for user


  output$Variable_Selector <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$file))
      return(NULL)
    inFile <- input$file
    myData <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    if (is.null(myData))
      return(NULL)
  })
})
```

**global.r**

```
myData = NULL
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one solution using the functions `observe` and `updateSelectInput` - with some other minor modifications to your code. To demonstrate I made the following two `csv` files with different column names:

```
Df1 <- data.frame(
  x=1:5,
  y=2*(1:5),
  z=3*(1:5))
##
Df2 <- data.frame(
  a=6:10,
  b=2*(6:10),
  c=3*(6:10),
  d=letters[1:5],
  stringsAsFactors=F)
##
write.csv(Df1,file="~/tempfiles/Df1.csv",row.names=F)
##
write.csv(Df2,file="~/tempfiles/Df2.csv",row.names=F)
```

---

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("My R Shiny App"),

  sidebarPanel(

    fileInput(
      'file', 
      'Choose file to upload.'
    ),

    selectInput(
      "y_input", 
      label = h5("Select Time Series/Response Variable"),
      ""
    )

  )

))
```

---

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  inFile <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      input$file
    }
  })

  myData <- reactive({
    if (is.null(inFile())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      read.csv(inFile()$datapath)
    }
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "y_input",
      choices=names(myData()))

  })

})
```

---

**global.R**:

```
myData <- NULL
```

---

And here are a couple of screenshots showing how the UI changes based on the uploaded file:

[image: Uploading <code>Df1.csv</code>]

[image: Uploading <code>Df2.csv</code>]

Comment: Thanks so much @nrussel. Can you provide a link that talks about observe and session?

Comment: You're welcome, [observe](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/observe) and [session](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html).